# Need help stopping a bicep deployment if a certain character is included in a secure parameter

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

I'm attempting to add validation to a bicep template to check if a secure parameter includes a '@' or '$' character and fail the deployment if those characters are found.

```
@secure()
@allowed([
  '???'
])
param secureParam string

var doesParamContainAtSign = contains( secureParam, '@')
var doesParamContainDollarSign = contains( secureParam, '$')

resource secureSecret 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets@2021-11-01-preview' = if(!doesParamContainAtSign || !doesParamContainDollarSign) {
  parent: key_vault
  name: 'secureSecret'
  properties: {
    value: secureParam
  }
}
```

I researched [parameter decorators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/parameters#decorators) that can be used to define "accepted" values for parameters, but is there a way to leverage this decorator and do some sort of string evaluation on the parameter?

I also researched the bicep function [contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/bicep-functions-string#contains), which would meet my criteria for doing a character check on the parameter, and I can use a conditional to *skip* the deployment, but I'd prefer the deployment to fail rather than conditionally deploy the secret.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to error out a bicep deployment, you'd need to deal with that before starting the deployment (eg. With [Azure Portal UI Custom Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-specs-create-portal-forms#customize-form), it can leverage regex for input sanitisation before deployment starts).

I think you've implemented this logic quite well inside bicep to prevent secret creation based on your detection logic. Ways of making the bicep error out are currently clumsy and shouldn't be relied upon.

Another option for some use cases could be to generate the secret in the bicep itself, save to keyvault and then return as an output the KeyVault Secret Id as a reference.